# ionic 4 native http get empty data in html

Tags: angular, native, ionic4

I am beginner in ionic 4. And I am trying to get json data from an api using native http. My code is working fine with a json data response, but the problem is I got empty data in html

json

```
{
  "userId": 1,
  "id": 1,
  "title": "delectus aut autem",
  "completed": false
}
```

main code :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http/ngx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

  object : any  ;
  constructor(private http: HTTP) {
   this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1',{},{})
   .then(data => {

    this.object = data

  })    .catch(error => this.object = error);
  }


}
```

if l use only object in html he is return json response

```
 {{object}}
```

[image]

but if l want get title form data json l got empty page

```
 {{object.title}}
```

Comment: any solution please ?

Comment: what does `{{object}}` print?

Comment: @AJT_82 json response

Comment: Yes, assumingly. But how does the response look like?

Comment: check my update question @AJT_82

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Digging into the documentation a bit, first of all, what the **[native http](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/)** returns is:

```ts
this.http.get('http://ionic.io', {}, {})
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data.status);
    console.log(data.data); // data received by server
    console.log(data.headers);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error.status);
    console.log(error.error); // error message as string
    console.log(error.headers);
  });
```

So your response is in `data.data` in above case. The image you posted, made me realize that we are dealing with a string! So, dug deeper and in the cordova docs I found that the response returned by native http, is indeed a string!

> [docs](https://github.com/silkimen/cordova-plugin-advanced-http#post) The success function receives a response object with 4 properties: status, data, url, and headers. status is the HTTP response code as numeric value. **data is the response from the server as a string**. url is the final URL obtained after any redirects as a string. headers is an object with the headers.

So what you need to do, is parse the response!

```ts
 this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1',{},{})
   .then(data => {
     this.object = JSON.parse(data.data)
   });
```

Comment: l dont know how to thank you . he is working now . thank you again

Comment: No problem, learnt something new myself, so it was mutually rewarding :D Have a nice weekend and happy coding!

Comment: Very nice answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things here. If you are using angular, and you want to provide data to your HTML code, then you are going to need to use the @component decorator at the top of this class.

Inside of that decorator, you'll add some metadata. Part of this metadata will be the folder reference of your html template that you want to be controlled by this now component. Your html doesn't know about the data in this class because they are not tied together in any way that angular can understand.

I would try something closer to this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-page-selector',
  templateUrl: './myPage.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./myPage.component.css']
})
export class HomePage {

  object : any  ;
  constructor(private http: HTTP) {
   this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1',{},{})
   .then(data => {

    this.object = data.data

  })    .catch(error => this.object = error);
  }
}
```

You would then have a an html file 'myPage.Component.html' that could then know about it's driving component.

```
<div>
{{object.title}}
</div>
```

I would look up the angular documentation and get familiar with the angular CLI. This would help you generate components and templates together and you can avoid some of this confusion.

Comment: I also agree with the assignation to data.data from the post above.

Comment: Ah okay @pabloescobar, that wasn't there when I submitted my answer. Thanks though.